# How Do I Defeat Lightning & Amodar?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

The Lightning & Lieutenant Amodar fight is one of the first DLC for FF 13-2. I'm having trouble beating them. I've tried taking out Amodar first, Lightning first, and also turtling while they use their more powerful attacks.

Any proper strategies, paradigms, or monsters to use against them?

Comment: I read 'Almodovar' and got confused - Spanish film directors would be slightly out of place in a FF game...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of strategies to use for them. I recommend maxing out all of your jobs and your three monsters having more then 2000 HP.

**Monsters**

- **Vodianoi** level 17 `COM`
- **Gremlin** level 40 `RAV`
- **Green Chocobo** level 27 `MED`

**Accessories**

Noel was 3 **Power Wristbands** and for Serah I used **Hypnocrown**, Durable and Delicate **Magician's Mark**.

**Paradigms**

`COM COM COM` Cerberus
`RAV COM RAV*` Relentless Assault
`RAV SAB RAV*` Smart Bomb
`RAV COM MED*` Diversity
`SAB SAB MED*` Safe Subversion
`MED MED MED` Salvation
The ones I've starred are the more critical ones I used. The all `COM` paradigm is nice to have if you cannot finish them before the stagger bar empties.

The fight can be broken up into three parts one is when, Lightning is alone and you just need to get her hp down to about 3/4 which isnt very hard, and the second phase is when Amodar joins the battle (`COM` `COM`) the two of them work more on party damage with Amodars grenade or him simply attacking all party members if close enough. Lighting dealing party damage with `Ruinga`. After about 2 mins in they change to either `SAB` `SYN`, `SAB` `MED` or `COM` `RAV`. When Amodar is a `SAB` he inflicts just about anything on the party member he attacks so I recommend going after him first, plus Lightning is easier to take out alone without his debuffs.

At the start of phase two I recommend either `RAV` `SAB` `RAV` if you think you're good enough, or `SAB` `SAB` `MED` to keep more HP. (*Note* my chocobo did die often so have many phoenix downs and potions, possibly if you desire remedys) you can only inflict `Deprotect` and `Deshell` on Lightning and `Imperil` and `Poison` on Amodar however you really only need `Imperil`. Once you have that on Amodar, switch to either `RAV` `COM` `RAV` or `RAV` `COM` `MED` and stagger him. He does have a lot of HP but if you either get his HP to 999.99 or about 1/3 of the way empty change to `COM` `COM` `COM` and you should be okay. This also works on Lightning, however Amodar like to switch to `SAB` and cast a lot of debuffs on your party.

Now comes the third phase, either Lightning or Amodar are alone and they cast a few buffs on themselves which cannot be dispelled. I recommend switching to `RAV` `SAB` `RAV` and repeating the above on them, and then switch to `RAV` `COM` `RAV` and try to stagger them. Before you can, they usually get off about 2 Feral Links but Lightnings is weaker and wont instantly kill your party members (except Noel). With this party I recommend having atleast 20 `Phoenix Downs` to revive your monster and Sarah or Noel if they die.

Comment: Good content, but rather hard to read.

Comment: It's a good guide if you can overlook the messiness of the writing. Had to get myself a coffee to read this.

Comment: I used a Dragoon (lv. 20), Cloudburst (lv. 28), and Green Chocobo (lv. 54) with Serah and Noel having their penultimate crystarium expansion almost complete, and this strategy worked exceedingly well. With my setup, only the Green Chocobo dies and it's usually only 2-3 times.

Answer (score 2):

Delta attack
Mystic Tower
Cerberus

Used Odin Weapons 140 Fragments

Monsters - Bunkerbeast lv. 70 and Tonberry lv .20

Run up the chain gauges with the first two paradigms and then shift to Cerberus for the kill.

Comment: To be fair, if you have 140 fragments, Odin weapons, and a Tonberry you could probably just do this fight with Relentless Assault.

Answer (score 2):

I used the following paradigms:

- COM RAV COM
- RAV RAV RAV
- SYN SAB SEN
- COM MED COM
- MED MED SEN

Try to have the SEN with one of the monsters - same for the RAV and COM.

Use the RAV RAV RAV so the stagger bar goes up fast, and when the enemies are staggered switch to COM RAV COM for more damage.  If you get hurt change to MED MED SEN so you can heal up while they are entertained with your SEN  monster.   Then go back to the same routing.

After you have Lightning alone let Noel be the leader so you can be close to her and watch for her over limit.  Once you see this switch to MED MED SEN.  The monster will provoke her and he will take the damage and survive the limit army of one.

Keep this up and you will beat them.  I only have the characters on lvl 56 for each of their classes.  It took me like 20 to 25 minutes to take them down.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's not exactly THAT hard. You don't need to be fully maxed out, but at least have most of them in the 70-55 range. It took me about 8 minutes.

The Monsters I used were Flanitor (MED) 3607 HP. Golden Chocobo (COM) 5372 HP. Munchkin Boss (RAV) 4054 HP.

The Stats of My Team were as Follows. Noel: ATB 5. Strength: 424. Magic: 310. Equipment: Kaiser Knuckles. Commando 73, Ravager 60, Sentinel 44, Saboteur 48, Synergist 44, Medic 38.

Serah: ATB 5. Commando 57. Ravager 73. Sentinel 46. Saboteur 32. Synergist 49. Medic 50.

Flanitor: ATB 4. Medic 40. Abilities Cure,Cura,Curasa,Raise,Cheer,Esuna,Esunada. Magic 631, Strength 454.

Golden Chocobo: ATB 4. Commando 20. Strength 572. Magic 397.

Munchkin Boss: ATB 4. Ravager 30. Strength 279. Magic 667.

With this team and equipment, I finished in 8 Minutes. 5 Stars.

There are three stages to this fight. Alone with Lightning, Lightning and Amodar, and Lightning by herself but much stronger.

I would recommend Paradigms: Mystic Tower,Diversity,Tri-Disaster,Cerberus,Combat Clinic, and Protection. You should start with Tri-Disaster. If you're a little health wary, switch (Rav,Rav,Rav) to (Rav,Med,Rav). The key here is to stagger them and use Cerberus to inflict as much damage as possible.

Now for what to do. Starting with Tri-Disaster, the first Lightning fight should really put up a fight. Just stagger her then take about a quarter of her life, then the second phase appears.

Lightning and Amodar are a tough pair and will take a little bit of skill. If you're health is Below 3500 on either characters , start with the Paradigm Protection. A Sentinel will attract any damage and a Medic will be healing the party while a Synergist Buffs your party. After you're buffed, switch to you Triple Ravager Paradigm and stagger AMODAR as soon as you can. He is the most dangerous with his Buffs, Potions, and Saboteur abilities so stagger him around three times using Tri-Disaster and use Cerberus during the stagger.

If you need to heal, Diversity is a good all-around Paradigm. For emergencies, use Salvation or Combat Clinic. Try to get Smite or Noel's Finishing Move just before the Stagger Period Ends. No matter what you do, if you stagger one of them, they will go into Double Dose (Med,Med). THis is your chance to buff your party, heal them, and also using this precious time to build up the chain gauge as fast as possible.

After Amodar is down, Lightning is alone. When you see her use Limit Break, regardless of what you're doing, go into Tortoise if you have the Paradigm. She will inflict massive damage on one enemy possible killing them with Low HP, so keep those Phoenix Downs ready. By now you have all you need to make them into Monster Crystals. Hope this Helps!

Answer (score 1):

I did beat them around level 30-40 of each role  on first try. The key is SEN monster, I use goblin chieftain which has around 7500 hp. The first fight is breeze. But second one you need to focus on one of them, it's a lot easier if you beat Lightning now. She will use cure often make sure you use SAB SAB SEN to debuff her before straggering. When you beat her, her companion will improves his strength. The key is POISON use it before straggering him or he will recover with medguard which will fully recovered his HP. Nothing need to be care much, your monster will take care of any damage without problem. Use potion instead of MED will buy a lot of time for you to draw your attacks.